# How to show correct Icon in IconButton Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a button in the AppBar and I want to change its icon on click, but nothing works.
If you check the type of the icon inside onPressed, then the condition is triggered depending on which button should be, but it is not displayed.

```
bool toggle = true;
late Widget searchWidget = IconButton(
  onPressed: (){
    setState(() {
      toggle = !toggle;
    });
  },
  icon: toggle ? const Icon(Icons.search) : const Icon(Icons.cancel),
);    
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      actions: [
        searchWidget,
        ],
      title: searchBar
    ),
    body: displayBody,
    bottomNavigationBar: _bottomMenu,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `searchWidget` to method to get updated UI,

```dart
 Widget searchWidget() => IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            toggle = !toggle;
          });
        },
        icon: toggle ? const Icon(Icons.search) : const Icon(Icons.cancel),
      );
```

And use like

```dart
  actions: [
          searchWidget(),
        ],
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you.
Not sure why it doesn't work with the field?

Comment: My assumption is `searchWidget` has been initialized  with `IconButton` at first place, changing inner elements is not changes is not effecting because it is not a method ,  `late keyword with declaration` also known as [`Lazy initialization`](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#lazy-initialization)